# How to update the SQL Server table based on different column value

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update table called people from:

[image]

to

[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: is e-mailaddress required/not null? will is always be domainname\emailaddress ?

Comment: Firstly you've posted data as an image, this isn't helpful, as nobody can copy/paste that data into an example if they want to prepare an answer. So you're not helping yourself there. Secondly, you've not shown any attempt at solving this problem, whether you have it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse out the beginning of the email address to add it to the domain name. Do that by finding the [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of the `@` symbol, then subtracting one. Use that value as the length parameter in a [`LEFT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function call.

Once you have the name from the email address, [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)enate it to the static value of your `domainname\`.

I included a `WHERE` clause that you may want to use if you have a large number of rows where the `Username` is already correct and you don't want to waste a bunch of writes replacing a string with a duplicate of that same string. You could leave the `WHERE` off if you prefer.

```
UPDATE People
  SET Username = CONCAT('domainname\',LEFT([E-mailAddress],CHARINDEX('@',[E-mailAddress])-1))
WHERE
  Username <> CONCAT('domainname\',LEFT([E-mailAddress],CHARINDEX('@',[E-mailAddress])-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on earlier versions (cause `CONCAT()` is for 2012+ versions) and also if you have `NULL`s in the `UserName` column, you can do like

```
CREATE TABLE T(
 [E-MailAddress] VARCHAR(50),
 UserName VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('abc@domainname.com', 'abc'),
('zxc@fhlbdm.com', NULL),
('MNO@domainname.com', 'MNO'),
('pqr@domainname.com', 'pq'),
('tyu@domainname.com', 'domainname\tyu');

UPDATE T
SET UserName = 'domainname\' + LEFT([E-MailAddress], CHARINDEX('@', [E-MailAddress])-1)
WHERE 'domainname\' + LEFT([E-MailAddress] , CHARINDEX('@', [E-MailAddress])-1) <> UserName
      OR
      UserName IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM T;
```